# How to change antd steps status using button

Tags: reactjs, antd

the code I am using :

```
onStepChange = current => {
    this.setState({ f1Status: 'process', f2Status: 'finish' });
}
```

The JSX:

```
<Steps onchange={onStepChange}
<Steps.Step status={this.state.f1Status}/>
<Steps.Step status={this.state.f2Status}/>
</Steps>
```

The above code is only pseduocode and/or bare minimum of what I thought should be provided, If there's any information I should add please tell me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is what am doing;

1. Get `Step` component from `Steps`
2. Initial state of step = 0
3. Make a function `nextStep` which will add 1 to the current step number (This function will be called by child components)
4. Declaring steps content array, content each step will have
5. Using the `Steps` component which receives a child of `Step` components rendered from a map of our steps content array declared in instructions above.
6. Just below the steps components, render each steps array content according to the current step being navigated.

```js
const { Step } = Steps

const SomeForm = (props) => {
  const [currentStep, changeStep] = useState(0)

  const nextStep = () => {
    changeStep(currentStep + 1)
  }

  //- Content
  const stepsArray = [
    {
      title: "Basic Information",
      content: <Basic nextStep={nextStep} handleBasicSubmit={handleBasic} />,
    },
    {
      title: "Location Information",
      content: <LocationSc nextStep={nextStep} handleLocationSubmit={handleLocation} />,
    },
    {
      title: "Post Property",
      content: <Post handlePostSubmit={handlePost} />,
    },
  ]

  return (
    <>
      <Row justify="center">
        <Col xs={16} md={24}>
          <Steps
            type="navigation"
            size="small"
            current={currentStep}
            onChange={(current) => changeStep(current)}
          >
            {stepsArray.map((item) => (
              <Step key={item.title} title={item.title} />
            ))}
          </Steps>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <article>
        <section>{stepsArray[currentStep].content}</section>
      </article>
    </>
  )
}
```